# Xerox Phaser 6010 printer not working in 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, printing, xerox

My laser printer xerox phaser 6010 doesn't work with 16.04 LTS. It is recognized and apparently accepts print jobs, but doesn't print and shows one of these messages:

> waiting for print completed

or

> inactive - rendering completed

It works fine with 14.04 LTS (settings seem to be the same) and Windows too.

Thanks,

Gerardo

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (via Dell 1760c) and tried the solution which worked for me under Ubuntu 14.04 and it didn't work, and also about 8 hours of other stuff and still no printing. I am sticking with Ubuntu 14.04 until I can get the printer to work (I use swoppable drives). Somewhat annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the 16.04.1 I installed today. I have a Xerox Phaser 6000B.

First, I tried other links saying to install cups and some `libscups*:i386` packages, did not seem to help. Then, I installed `gdebi`. Downloaded the old recommended Debian driver from Xerox web side. Unpacked the zip file and installed that Debian driver using `apt gdebi ~/Download/xxx.deb`.

Then go into the normal printer from system deleted the printer, add a new printer with the 6000 driver.

Now, it works. My best guest is that it is the last step that made it work but I do not know if the first steps are needed too.

Comment: sudo apt install gdebi
 2051  sudo gdebi Downloads/deb_1.01_20110210/xerox-phaser-6000-6010_1.0-1_i386.

Comment: Uninstalled libscups2:i386, it still works. seem like using the gdebi package is the only way

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me, but this did-
http://douglask.fog.org/home/xerox-phaser-6010n

This part was essential to get the printer working-

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libcupsimage2:i386
```

> 1. Download the .DEB driver that Xerox supplies (Here's a [link for your
>      convenience](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6010/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en)).
> 2. It comes packaged as a .zip file, so extract the .zip file.
> 3. Now that we have the required driver handy, we can pre-configure your system:
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386  
>    sudo apt-get update  
>    sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libcupsimage2:i386
>    ```
> 4. Next, install the printer driver and any dependencies it may have.  The apt-get command will install any missing dependencies and complete
>      the installation of the driver if needed.
>
>    ```
>    cd /path/to/driver  
>    sudo dpkg -i xerox-phaser-6000-6010_1.0-1_i386.deb  
>    apt-get -f install
>    ```
> 5. Now, use the printer applet in your system settings to add the printer.  Ubuntu should auto-detect the printer and the driver.